# Understanding the difference in syntax for an if_else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am new to if_else statements and I'm wondering if someone could help me understand what some of my colleague's code means (they are no longer working where I am). I am using if_else statements to identify/flag temperature data from a set of logger deployments (ie. I don't want data that has been logged after they've been retrieved, or between retrieval and the next deployment etc.). Some have been deployed and retrieved once (B in my example) and some have been deployed twice (A and C in my example).

Here is a general look into the dataset (df):

| temp | Datetime_log | deploy_1 | deploy_2 | retrieve_1 | retrieve_2 | Logger |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.7 | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | A |
| 3.6 | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | A |
| 3.4 | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | A |
| 3.1 | Datetime | Datetime |  | Datetime |  | B |
| 1.5 | Datetime | Datetime |  | Datetime |  | B |
| 1.5 | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | Datetime | C |

I am working off some old code of another colleague and am wondering what these two statements 'say', or what they mean.

1. `df$flag1 <- if_else(is.na(df$deploy_2),0,if_else(df$Datetime_log>retrieve_1 & df$Datetime_log<deploy_2,1,0))`

   I assume the above means: If deploy_2 is NA assign it as 0, but if not, and, Datetime_log is > retrieve_1 & < deploy_2, assign it as 1.
2. `df$flag2 <- if_else(is.na(df$deploy_2), if_else(df$Datetime_log>df$retrieve_1, 1,0),0)`

   I assume the above means: If deploy_2 is NA, assign it as 0, but if not, and, Datetime_log is > retrieve_1, assign it as 1?

I am very confused over the placement of the '0's as well. As in the first statement, the 0 was placed after the first if_else, and in the second statement, the 0 was placed at the end of the entire statement.

Please, if anyone could correct me or help me out here I would be so grateful! Just looking for someone to very plainly spell out how to read those statements. That will help me with the additional filters I have to make. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: To start - `if_else()` is from the tidyverse.  The base R version is called `ifelse()`.  See this page for details:  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html

Comment: The first statement is basically replacing `NA` values with 0 (`is.na(df$deploy_2),0`). The second statement appears to be evaluating if `deploy_2` is NA, and if it is NA, it's replacing it with 1 (or 0) depending on how `Datetime_log>df$retrieve_1` evaluates, otherwise, if `deploy_2` is not NA, it's assigning a 0.

Answer (score 5):

Your interpretation of #1 is correct, but #2 is incorrect. Generally `if_else` works as `if_else(condition, result if true, result if false)`. In your code multiple `if_else` statements are *nested* one inside another, so in these cases one of the results is another `if_else` statement (which will be evaluated for its own result).

In #2 what is happening is *If `deploy_2` is `NA`, then {(nested) if `Datetime_log >  retrieve_1` assign 1, else assign 0} else assign 0*. To summarize with some nicer code formatting, naming the arguments, and a table of what happens:

```
## #2 from the question
if_else(
  condition = is.na(df$deploy_2),
  true = if_else(
      condition = df$Datetime_log > df$retrieve_1,
      true = 1,
      false = 0),
  false = 0
)

is.na(deploy_2) | Datetime_log > retrieve_1 | What to assign
----------------|---------------------------|---------------
TRUE            | TRUE                      | 1
TRUE            | FALSE                     | 0 
FALSE           | not checked               | 0
```

You do have #1 correct, but to present it in the same way we could write:

```
df$flag1 <- if_else(
    condition = is.na(df$deploy_2),
    true = 0,
    false = if_else(
        condition = df$Datetime_log > retrieve_1 & df$Datetime_log < deploy_2,
        true = 1,
        false = 0
    )
)

                | Datetime_log > retrieve_1     |
is.na(deploy_2) |  AND Datetime_log < deploy_2  | What to assign
----------------|-------------------------------|----------------
TRUE            | not checked                   | 0
FALSE           | TRUE                          | 1
FALSE           | FALSE                         | 0
```

As pointed out in comments, your code **mostly** uses `df$` to specify that it is using the columns *in the `df` data frame. However, #1 **does not use `df$` for `retrieve_1` and `deploy_2`** which seems dangerous - rather than looking in the data frame for columns of those names, it is looking in the Global Environment for objects of that name.

(Also note that, if these codes appear inside `dplyr` functions like `mutate` or `summarize` then the `df$` prefixes are not needed. But, as written, the `df$` prefixes are probably needed.)

Comment: Of the 3 answers basically saying the same thing, this is the most nicely formatted and complete.  I'm not sure the protocol - do I leave mine up to demonstrate consensus but upvote this one, or should I delete mine?

Comment: I don't think demonstrating consensus with multiple answers is very useful. I would say, if there are elements of yours that you think are missing here or covered better in yours either (a) edit your answer to focus on those areas and frame it as a complement to my answer, or (b) you're welcome to edit my answer to include those parts. If you don't see elements like that that need preserving, if I were you I would delete. (But there's not really any harm in keeping it up either...)

Comment: *"this is the most nicely formatted and complete"* - thank you :D

Comment: I agree that this one is easiest to read and all answers are essentially the same. The only thing that I think is worth noting is that #1 does not compare to df$retrieve_1 or df$deploy_2, but to retrieve_1 and deploy_2,  which makes it behave very differently from #2..

Comment: Thank you all so much! This is very clear :)

Answer (score 1):

For general reference see the documentation here:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html

It's important to note that this version of the if-else implementation is vectorised, to the first argument is not necessarily a single true/false but could be a logical vector instead.

I will break down the code here.  The tabbing/spacing is not how I would write the code, it just helps line up the comments:

```
df$flag1 <- if_else(
    is.na(df$deploy_2),   # condition for outer if_else
                     0,   # what to return if condition is TRUE
    if_else(              # but if the condition is FALSE... 
        df$Datetime_log>retrieve_1 & df$Datetime_log<deploy_2,  #second condition
                                                            1,  # action if 2nd cond TRUE
                                                            0)  # action if 2nd cond also FALSE
)
```

note that there is no replacing. When you say "If deploy_2 is NA assign it as 0" you may already realise this, but it's more "If `deploy_2` is NA, assign this slot in `flag1` as 0"

Similarly:

```
df$flag2 <- if_else(
    is.na(df$deploy_2),                  # first condition
    if_else(                             # if TRUE, enter secondary if_else
        df$Datetime_log>df$retrieve_1,   # |secondary condition
        1,                               # |if 2ry condition TRUE
        0),                              # |if 2ry condition FALSE
    0)                                   # if original condition FALSE
```

Incidentally, I think the general pattern that would be used now is:

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(flag1 = if_else(is.na(deploy_2), 0, if_else(Datetime_log>retrieve_1 & Datetime_log<deploy_2, 1, 0)),
           flag2 = if_else(is.na(deploy_2), if_else(Datetime_log>dretrieve_1, 1, 0), 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse()` and `if_else()` both use a syntax of `condition, 'if true', 'if false'`. That means you first define what you would like to test, and then what you would like to do if the test passes and then what to do if it does not.

The difference between

```
df$flag1 <- if_else(is.na(df$deploy_2), 
                    0,
                    if_else(df$Datetime_log > retrieve_1 & 
                            df$Datetime_log < deploy_2, 
                            1,
                            0)
                     )
```

and

```
df$flag2 <- if_else(is.na(df$deploy_2), 
                    if_else(df$Datetime_log > df$retrieve_1,
                            1,
                            0),
                     0)
```

is that the first (`flag1`) will check if `deploy_2` is `NA` and if it is it will return `0`. Otherwise it will check if `Datetime_log` is greater than `retrieve_1` AND if `Datetime_log` is also less than `deploy_2`, if both are true it will return `1`, otherwise `0`. Please note that for some reason, this appears to refer to variables called `retrieve_1` and `deploy_2`, not to columns of the dataframe.

`flag2` will return `0` if `deploy_2` is not `NA`. If `deploy_2` is `NA` it will check if the `Datetime_log` column value is greater than the `retrieve_1` column. If `Datetime_log` is greater, it will return `1`, otherwise it will return `0`

Both could also be rewritten using dplyr functions `case_when` and `mutate` like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(flag1 = case_when(Datetime_log > retrieve_1 & Datetime_log < deploy_2 ~ 1,
                           TRUE ~ 0),
         flag2 = case_when(Datetime_log > retrieve_1 ~ 1,
                           TRUE ~ 0))
```

This would compare within the dataframe, to compare to an external variable that would need to be pasted, but ideally this should also have a different name not used for columns...